# Virtual CD is not connecting in IPMI JViewer

Tags: linux, virtualization, ipmi, iso, bmc

I am not able to mount the ISO image in the IPMI Remote JViewer.
Earlier I mounted the CD and installed the OS and did some installations also.
Now I am not able to mount. It's not connecting.
When I check the /media folder, already there are cdrom and cdrom0 folders which are empty.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mount it inside the os?

Comment: No. mounted before booting

Comment: Well, then mount it. Linux will not do it magically by itself.

Comment: I am talking about a management server. it has to connect. os itself installed using the same virtual cd mount. now only its not connecting